# Using connections with managed identities during local development

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App Standard that has originally been developed using the online designer. The applications creates entries in an azure storage table using built-in action. The connection to storage account is using a system generated managed identity, which has appropriate roles assigned. This works fine while running in the cloud. Sample connection config:

```
"serviceProviderConnections": {
    "azureTables-2": {
      "parameterValues": {
        "tableStorageEndpoint": "@appsetting('azureTables_tableStorageEndpoint')",
        "authProvider": {
          "Type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
        }
      },
      "serviceProvider": {
        "id": "/serviceProviders/azureTables"
      },
      "displayName": "storage-account"
    }
  }
```

Now I'm trying to switch to local development so I can launch and debug the Logic App using Visual Studio Code. However, when I try to run this I'm getting following error:

[image]

It makes sense to me because my local application doesn't have a managed identity assigned with access to the storage account in cloud. Can I enable manage identity access for my local Logic App instance? If not, what alternative do I have?

Comment: I’d suggest you raise that with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I enable manage identity access for my local Logic App instance?

Yes, you can enable managed identity for local logic app. You can use already created api connection while connecting to storage or you can create new api connection with storage account.

- I have created a logic app in logic app as shown below,
  [image]
- This logic app is simple recurrence trigger with one create table action in azure table storage.
- While adding create table action I have chosen authentication as Managed identity.
  [image]
  [image]
- Once logic app runs, it created a table in Azure table storage.
  [image]
  [image]
- Connection string code that worked for me looks like below,
  [image]

```
   {
 "managedApiConnections": {
   "azuretables": {
     "api": {
       "id": "/subscriptions/subcriptionid/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/azuretables"
     },
     "connection": {
       "id": "/subscriptions/subcriptionid/resourceGroups/rsg/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azuretables"
     },
     "connectionRuntimeUrl": "https://1111.09.common.logic-location.azure-apihub.net/apim/azuretables/999999/",
     "authentication": {
       "type": "Raw",
       "scheme": "Key",
       "parameter": "@appsetting('azuretables-connectionKey')"
     }
   }
 },
 "serviceProviderConnections": {
   "azureTables": {
     "parameterValues": {
       "tableStorageEndpoint": "@appsetting('azureTables_tableStorageEndpoint')",
       "authProvider": {
         "Type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
       }
     },
     "serviceProvider": {
       "id": "/serviceProviders/azureTables"
     },
     "displayName": "mi9"
   }
 }
}
```

Reference MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-visual-studio-code).

- If this approach did not work for you, as suggested by @ Skin raise support request with Microsoft.